# 18.04 won't boot with Tesla (Titan V) GPU

Tags: nvidia, 18.04

I have a desktop with two Titan V GPUs.
I upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04, now I get a blank screen after BIOS.
I tried 390 and 396 drivers, no luck.

Any ideas? I'd hate to have to install 17.10 from scratch.

Comment: You don't get a grub screen at all? Or you mean it goes blank after the grub menu?

Comment: It does boot into Grub. But afterwards I get a blank screen with the /dev/numel1n1p2: clean 60000/6000000 files 2000000/20000000 blocks (I made up the numbers) message, basically it doesn't get further